# Google Script can't find file for one user but can for owner

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have an app script which should pull a file from a shared folder in google drive. It has worked in the past but recently stopped working after no changes. The code runs fine when I execute it, however when another user runs the program it errors.

the error given is *TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasNext' of undefined*

To pull the file I am using

```
var file;
[other code]
file=DriveApp.getFilesByName("file.pdf")
if(file.hasNext()){
    var attachment=file.next()
}
```

Comment: Something must have change in the ownership of files.  Check with your admin because there have been several security changes recently which may affect sharing issues.  I don't  know them specifically because I have no other people in my domain.

Comment: That error is a bit strange, because `getFilesByName()` returns an iterator even if it doesn't find any files, so `file` shouldn't be undefined. Maybe check if you can reproduce it without this [other code] part or with another file with the same permissions?

Comment: @Cooper you were right. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Google recently changed security policies which changed ownership of files. Simply reopening the files fixed the problem